# Binding two-way to a readonly property

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I've got a read-only property on a model object, but want to bind two-way to it. When the binding source should get updated, I want the update to instead be 'redirected' to a separate method that plugs into our controller infrastructure to perform the update and generate a new model with the change property. Simply using a Binding on a read-only property and adding a handler to the `Binding.TargetUpdated` event doesn't work (throws an InvalidOperationException, specifying the property should be read-only).

There's a simple solution to this (create a copy of the model, with read-write properties that do the redirect for me) but I don't really want to have to copy all my model objects. Is there a way of doing this programatically?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you binding your view directly to the model with no intermediate? where do you get ItemsSource for comboboxes (for example) from?

Comment: All the values for comboboxes are generated by the controller. I typically put a `ICollectionView` between any collections and the `DataContext` so I can be notified of changes and call back to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on custom markup extension which setups a two way binding for some dependency property. The binding uses some kind of wrapper with writable property as a source. The wrapper calls the infrastructure code to update and generate new model after property changed.

Below example with hard coded scenario, but I think the idea is quite clear.

```
namespace MyApp
{

public class MyModel
{
    //readonly property
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public MyModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Model = new MyModel("default");
    }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    //writable property to enable two-way binding
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewModel.Model.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            //call your infrastructure method to 
            //update and generate new model
            ViewModel.Model = new MyModel((string)value);
        }
    }
}

[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Object))]
public class CustomBinding : MarkupExtension
{
    //you can add any properties here for your infrastructure method call
    //public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var provideValueTarget = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        var binding = new Binding()
        {
            //get whatever you need from target element to setup the binding and wrapper
            Source = new Wrapper()
            {
                ViewModel = (provideValueTarget.TargetObject as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyViewModel
            },
            Path = new PropertyPath("Value")
        };
        var result = binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        return result;
    }
}

}
```

XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
    <MyApp:MyViewModel />
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
    <TextBox Text="{MyApp:CustomBinding}" />
<StackPanel />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get away without binding to a new intermediate object. Some might call it a view model. I was wondering whether a custom `IValueConverter` might be able to intercept the write operation as you need in `ConvertBack`, but I'm reasonably sure that the binding system won't even try to call the converter if the source property isn't writable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `ExpandoObject` - given a read-only model object, this generates a read-write model at runtime that calls the controller method whenever any property changes:

```
public static dynamic GetAdapterFor(IController controller, object modelObj)
{
    if (modelObj == null)
        return null;

    ExpandoObject obj = new ExpandoObject();

    // add all the properties in the model
    foreach (var prop in modelObj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj).Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(modelObj, null));
    }

    // add the handler to update the controller when a property changes
    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)obj).PropertyChanged += (s, e) => UpdateController(controller, e.PropertyName, ((IDictionary<string, object>)s)[e.PropertyName]);

    return obj;
}

private static void UpdateController(IController controller, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    controller.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, propertyValue);
}
```